# Nodejs process.report is undefined?

Tags: node.js

In nodejs I'm doing:

```
import * as process from 'process';

console.log(process.report); // undefined
```

and I'm getting undefined. "node -v" gives me v16.13.2.

Does anyone knows why?

Comment: is there any specific reason you are using import over require?

Comment: node himself in examples uses import so do I 
https://nodejs.org/api/process.html#processreport

Comment: wow I have just checked and it is working when I do require:

`let process = require('process');

console.log(process.report); `
why it's not working with import syntax?

Comment: im not really sure why exactly it doesnt work so someone else may have to answer thst for you, but its probably the way you were importing the module. i normally do `import { a, b ,c } from 'module'` or `import module from 'module'` depending on what im trying to do and it both works for me.

Comment: @ArtoAvag looks like you found a NodeJS bug ;) https://github.com/nodejs/node/issues/41774

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like the [docs](https://nodejs.org/api/process.html#processreport) are wrong and the process module is not fully esm ready.

```
import { report } from 'process';
         ^^^^^^
SyntaxError: The requested module 'process' does not provide an export named 'report'
```

Above error is the reason, why `import * as process from  'process'` gives `undefined`.

You can use the default export or use CommonJs for the time being I would argue.

```
import process from 'process';

console.log(process.report);
```